# Bash capturing in brace expansion

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

What would be the best way to use something like a capturing group in regex for brace expansion. For example:

```
touch {1,2,3,4,5}myfile{1,2,3,4,5}.txt
```

results in all permutations of the numbers and 25 different files. But in case I just want to have files like `1myfile1.txt`, `2myfile2.txt`,... with the first and second number the same, this obviously doesn't work. Therefore I'm wondering what would be the best way to do this?
I'm thinking about something like capturing the first number, and using it a second time. Ideally without a trivial loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your Q to include testable inputs, required outputs and your best attempt to solve your problem. I think you're going to need a `for` loop. Good luck.

Comment: Sure, I'm aware of loops, but capturing is not possible somehow?

Comment: Are you talking about matching something like `'/^[[:digit:]]+myfile[[:digit:]]+.txt/'` (extended regex)? Or, you could write `printf "%s\n" {1,2,3,4,5}myfile{1,2,3,4,5}.txt` to a temporary file and use `grep -f tmpfile ...` for matching purposes.

Comment: There are regular-expression capture groups in `bash`, but nothing for brace expansion.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. This answers the core of my question.

Comment: I'll have to look at the `bash` manual again under capture groups! Sorry for the mis-information and Glad you found a solution you like. Here's another `for` loop solution , `for n in {1..5} ; do touch ${n}FileName${n}.txt ; done`  Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: Don't worry, I know everyone in SO is just trying to help. There was probably just some misunderstanding, or the formulation of my question was also not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWK to do that:

```sh
echo {1..5} | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{print $1"filename"$1".txt"}' | xargs touch
```

Explanation:

> echo {1..5} - prints range of numbers
>   tr ' ' '\n' - splits numbers to separate lines
>   awk '{print $1"filename"$1}' - enables you to format output using previously printed numbers
>   xargs touch - passes filenames to touch command (creates files)

Comment: Or you could just use a `for` loop in `awk`.

Comment: Or `printf '%d\n' {1..5} | xargs -I{} touch {}filename{}.txt`

Comment: Instead of  `printf` you could use awk's `system("touch " $1"filename"$1".txt")` (with parenthesis) to execute it in awk.

Answer (score 4):

Not using a regex but a [for loop](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) and sequence ([seq](https://ss64.com/bash/seq.html)) you get the same result:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5); do touch ${i}myfile${i}.txt; done
```

Or tidier:

```
 for i in $(seq 1 5); 
 do 
   touch ${i}myfile${i}.txt; 
 done
```

As an example, using `echo` instead of `touch`:

```
➜ for i in $(seq 1 5); do echo ${i}myfile${i}.txt; done
1myfile1.txt
2myfile2.txt
3myfile3.txt
4myfile4.txt
5myfile5.txt
```

Comment: Don't use `seq`. If you are using `bash`, just use the C-style for loop: `for ((i=1;i<=5;i++)); do`. If you are trying to be POSIX-compliant, then `seq` isn't part of POSIX either, and you would use a `while` loop: `i=1; while [ "$i" -le 5 ]; do ...; i=$((i+1); done`.

Answer (score 3):

Variation on MTwarog's answer with one less pipe/subprocess:

```
$ echo {1..5} | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -I '{}' touch {}myfile{}.txt
$ ls -1 *myfile*
1myfile1.txt
2myfile2.txt
3myfile3.txt
4myfile4.txt
5myfile5.txt
```